# HSQLDB 2.4 How to use UNIX_MILLIS() as default value for BIGINT column

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I run the next SQL (JDBC)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PUBLIC.MY_DATA(
ID BIGINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
...,
LAST_MODIFIED BIGINT DEFAULT UNIX_MILLIS() NOT NULL)
```

and get SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: UNIX_MILLIS

But according to the [documentation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html)

> UNIX_MILLIS ( [  ] )
>
> This function returns a BIGINT value. With no parameter, it returns the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01. With a DATE or TIMESTAMP parameter, it converts the argument into number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01. (HyperSQL)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why not use a proper `TIMESTAMP` column?

Comment: we format last modified column on frontend according to selected user locale and frontend use milliseconds

Comment: You can do all that with real timestamps as well

Comment: I'll switch to TIMESTAMP with default NOW() value

Comment: You can create the tablet in PGS syntax compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the definition of the `DEFAULT` clause (in [table creation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_table_creation)), and the fact that what is allowed in there is limited to

> ```
> <default option> ::= <literal> | <datetime value function> | USER
> | CURRENT_USER | CURRENT_ROLE | SESSION_USER | SYSTEM_USER |
> CURRENT_CATALOG | CURRENT_SCHEMA | CURRENT_PATH | NULL
> ```

And `<datetime value function>` is defined as

> datetime value function
>
> ```
> <datetime value function> ::= ...
> ```
>
> Specify a function that returns a datetime value. The supported
>   datetime value functions are listed and described in the [Built In
>   Functions](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html) chapter.

As `UNIX_MILLIS` does not return a datetime value, but a `BIGINT`, it is entirely possible that `UNIX_MILLIS` is not considered a `<datetime value function>`, and therefor not available in the `DEFAULT` clause.

This seems to be supported by looking at the [parser of the default clause](https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/svn/6082/tree//base/trunk/src/org/hsqldb/ParserTable.java#l1847), which filters allowed expressions based on their result type.

As a tip, I haven't tested it, but it is possible that enabling PostgreSQL compatibility mode might allow you to use `DEFAULT UNIX_TIME()` or maybe `DEFAULT (UNIX_TIME())`.

Comment: Correct tip. This kind of definition of the default is allowed in PostgreSQL compatibility mode.